# "A series from one to three items" - is it syntactically correct construction?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> A compound file name is the file name that consists of multiple *descriptive elements*, which are separated by *connectors*. A connector is a series from one to three hyphens.
>
> File name: `george_lucas--star_wars-episode1-phantom_menace`
>
> Naming scheme: `[director]--[movie title]-[subtitle]-[subsubtitle]`

My question is whether it is correct to use the word *series* in such a context? The word *series* is completely valid when we talk about 2 or more consecutive items (in our example, hyphens), but single hyphens are treated as connectors as well. Single items are normally not called "series" of something. How would you fix this passage?

Comment: You haven't explained what ***three*** consecutive hyphens would be used for, but as a general principle I don''t think "series" is a useful term to describe three "symbols" that only differ in that the actual "compound symbol" consists of one, two, or three consecutive instances of the same "subsymbol". You might get somewhere with ***sequence***, though.

Comment: File naming is off-topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because choosing names for software things is specifically outside put site's remit per our [help].

Comment: *A connector is one to three hyphens.*

Comment: @tchrist: The question is not off topic; OP is as asking about the wording of a sentence, not file naming. *A connector is a series from one to three hyphens.* A series of one?

Comment: @TinfoilHat Okay. Probably he doesn't know *sequence* from *series*.

Comment: I see no reason why representing a series or interval of numbers would not have the same starting point as representing a particular number of things. And since we normally say "a series **of** *x* items," it seems logical to express a series or interval as "a series **of**  *x* to *y* items." A second common way of expressing such series or intervals is to emphasize the endpoints of the numerical range by including "from" before the first term, giving us "a series **of from** *x* to *y* items." I have rarely encountered the form "a series **from** *x* to *y* items," however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, 'a series from one to three items' leaves an impression that the series somehow spans the space between one item and three items, rather than that it consists of at least one item, but no more than three items, which appears to have been intended. As Mr. Yargs has pointed out in a comment, an *of* is needed to convey that the series consist of these items: the formulation should thus be 'a series of from one to three items' or, better, 'a series of one to three items'.

Setting that aside, can one speak of a series that consists of only one item? The answer depends on one's audience. An audience trained in the sciences, engineering, or some related field, won't see anything strange about using the term *series* (or the related terms *sequence* and *set*) for something that, in fact, has only one member, as long as its nature allows for having more. But then, people with such training tend to use *series* with a very precise meaning that is not very useful for referring to one to three indistinguishable hyphens, as has been pointed out by FumbleFingers in a comment. An audience without such training is likely to find the idea of a one-member series (or set or sequence) confusing regardless of what it consists of.

The problem can be entirely avoided by simply saying that a connector consist of one to three hyphens.